# illegal latitude value for [GeoDistanceSort] in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

Having an issue with geo distance sorting with elasticsearch where an error is being returned when attempting to define the location pin. Using the Elastica PHP client.

```
$base->addSort([
    '_geo_distance' => [
        'location' => $location,
        'order' => 'asc',
        'unit' => 'm'
    ]
]);
```

The error is;

> illegal latitude value [269.58378318697214] for [GeoDistanceSort] [reason: all shards failed]

This suggests the value of the latitude is >180 but the value is only 51.561965753874624 with a longitude of -0.38245278430174103 (as retrieved from google maps).

I've checked the values are still as above before they are entered into the sort function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue to be that elasticsearch doesn't like how accurate the map location is!

I implemented the following to round the values to 6 decimal places, and it worked a treat.

```
foreach ($mapcentre as $deg) {
    $location[] = round($deg, 6);
}
```